# How to find Shortest Route between two points in PostGIS without using pgRouting?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I want to find **shortest route** between two points stored in **PostGIS** database. I know about **pgRouting** functionalities but I don't want to use it because of data processing/topology creation processes.

**Is their any such function/functions in PostGIS to achieve the same?**

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html

Comment: any routing solution will require topology

Comment: Why do you tag this question with "pgRouting", if you're not asking for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the shortest route between two points using PostGIS with `ST_Distance` (if you want to know the distance) or with `ST_MakeLine` (for the geometry):

- http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html
- http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html

If you want to use the network for routing, then you need a network topology. You could try something like [pggraph](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/pggraph), but `source` and `target` attributes are required as well.